# Chart is disappearing during # link

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, chart.js

The canvas is added in a separate HTML file (dashboard.html)

dashboard.html is added to the main HTML (home.html) page by using the ng-view and ng-view is inside of ng-if

The chart is disappearing when the # hyperlink is clicked from the main page (home.html)

Comment: any one, who could help me ? :-(

Answer (score 0):

What's the id of the parent element of #canvas-holder?
You have a bootstrap js event on your hyperlink; which toggles(hide or show) the target element.

```
data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#{{x.mfn}}"
```